# converting the pandas dataframe column type from object based on actual value of column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyspark

I have used below code to convert the spark data frame to pandas data frame.

```
trainDF=df.toPandas()
```

where df is spark data frame and trainDF is the pandas dataframe.

but the problem is, all the data types of each column in pandas data frame becomes object.

```
44640 non-null object
44640 non-null object
44640 non-null object
44640 non-null object
44640 non-null object
1440 non-null object
44640 non-null object
44640 non-null object
44640 non-null object
44640 non-null object
44640 non-null object
```

tried using infer objects function to convert to actual data types, still no luck.

```
trainDF=trainDF.infer_objects()
```

is there any way to change the  data type based on actual content of the column.

Comment: Please post a small [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples).